# Reset a stack history of an Ionic 3 tab

Tags: typescript, ionic2, ionic3

When playing with tabs, I take an example of an ionic app with 2 tabs (tab1 and tab2). With tab1 I can go to tab1->page1->page2 (through the navigation).
But the crucial scenario for is that when I click away from my current tab(tab1) to tab2 and come back to click on tab1 I get page2 in front of me but I need to get the stack reset and get tab1 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I find till now, especially with few number of pages is to implement that hook:

```
 ionViewDidLeave(){
    this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
  }
```

Some other solution also worked for me:

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(MyPage);
```

Comment: Poptoroot() also forces leaving all pages if level is more than 2. Try tab->page1->page2. When calling didleave of page1, that of page2 also is called. So there is not perfect way

Answer (score 2):

If you only have a small set of pages that you are working with you can hook into the lifecycle hook for the view leave and trigger a pop to the root.

```
  ionViewDidLeave() {
    this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
  }
```

Comment: goToRoot worked for me, but reading the API popToRoot looks like the correct answer. I am going to update mine.