# How to push the tabs to deafult page whenever it gets clicked in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I have mainTabs Page in which there are 5 pages
1)Home
)search
3)add
4)notify
5)profile

In search, it is also a tabpage having 2 tabs
1)search video
2)search people

in search video there is a list of videos and when I click on a video it opens a new page playVideo Page.

So at very first when app opens and we click on searchtab then it navigate to search video page and in search video when I click on a video it navigates to play video page.

home->searchtab->searchvideo->playvideo

but whenever I click to another page and reopens the search tab, it still navigate to play video page instead of search video.

home->searchtab->searchvideo->playvideo->notify->searchtab->playvideo

I have tried many things but not find any solution to pop playvideo page at every instance when i click on any other tab

Answer (score 0):

when u leave the playVideo page (onDidLeave) close the tab navigation.
Each tab keeps its navigation history, so when u navigate back to that tab, you will find everything as u left previously.

to avoid this u need to close your navigation on leave

Comment: i have called ionViewDidLeave() in playvideo but this method gets called when i change the search tabs and not when i change the main tabs like notification.

Comment: you need to use that event to reset the navigation

Comment: how to I pop playvideoPage when i  change the main tabs \

Answer (score 0):

```
ionViewDidLeave() {
    this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
  }
```

[Reset a stack history of an Ionic 3 tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47857967/reset-a-stack-history-of-an-ionic-3-tab)

Comment: I am in tab and I put this peice of code in tabs.ts still no luck

Comment: Man, I put the link u were supposed to read.. u have to put that function into the video player page.. follow the logic: when did leave the page reset its navigation history

Comment: I have gone through this link,but PlayVideoPage doesn't call ionViewDidLeave() method when we change the main tabs i.e. from searchTab to notifyTab,It calls ionViewDidLeave() when I change the searchVideo tab to PeopleTab.....actually   there are two levels of tab 1) is main tabs having four tabs and second level is search tabs having two tabs now tell me what to do @NikRubblers

Comment: u need to find the life cycle hooks relevant for ur case, google life cycle hooks. Its a bit strange, ionViewDidLeave should be called every time the actual view is left. try to move the code at tab level, but I repeat, it looks very strange.